# Exit whenever a warning is thrown

Tags: python, error-handling, warnings

I'm getting divide by zero (and other, similar) `Warning`s in my code --- these "shouldn't" [1] be happening --- but they're hard to track down because no backtrace is provided.  **Is there a way to make python raise an `Error` and throw a backtrace any time a `Warning` occurs?**

In a perfect world I'd be looking for something I can set in the beginning like:

```
DEBUG = True
...
sys.DemandPerfection(DEBUG)    # Exit on all Warnings
...
```

[1]: In terms of my *desired* results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just pass the command line option [`-W error`](https://docs.python.org/dev/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W) to Python interpreter or set [`PYTHONWARNINGS`](https://docs.python.org/dev/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONWARNINGS) to `error`.
But I think the solution you want is

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('error')
```

which should also work for IPython (you may want to put it into [startup directory](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/overview.html#startup-files) for convenience).

Comment: Awesome!  Is there anyway I can do this in `ipython` as-well (i.e. when using `%run`)?